# How do I get past the "Finish partitioning and write changes to disk" during automated UEFI install?

Tags: uefi, virtualization, kickstart

I am using ubuntu 18.04 with virt-install (--boot uefi) and a kickstart ks.cfg file. The disk partition and %pre information is ignored when using UEFI.

## Disk partitioning information

part /boot/efi --fstype efi  --ondisk=vda --size 256
part /         --fstype ext4 --ondisk=vda --size 1    --asprimary --grow

## Preseed Information

%pre
preseed partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
preseed partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

It doesn't matter what is put into those two sections, everything is ignored. Once I manually hit enter to accept the partition information the installation continues to a successful build.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I had an issue similar to this and adding this to `ks.preseed` solved it for me:

```
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

This is the relevant `txt.cfg` section for reference:

```
default install
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed ---
```